# How to save 4096 doubles per row in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

I'm working on an application that requires me to store and access a (n x 4096) matrix of doubles in a database where n could be as large as 10-20000.

I'm currently using MYSQL for the database and InnoDB as storage engine. The maximum column number is 1000 so one solution would be to split the table in five. Is there another way of doing this? I would preferably keep the DB easy to use if possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: Does the data need to be in a database? Do you have other attributes attached to these rows?

Comment: What will be done with these numbers?  Data analysis?  Matrix multiplication?  Something else?  How you want to store the data will depend on how you want to use the data.

Comment: The reason for me to want to use a database to make the data easily accessible. I have used csv files before but as the number of files grow this approach becomes worse and worse.

Besides the 4096 doubles there is a time stamp attached.

Also, the data will be used for data analysis later on.

Comment: If the data doesn't need to be searched or cross-referenced in anyway in the database, why not store it in a serialized form in a text field?

Comment: Seems like you need to rethink your design. 4096 columns just seems ... wrong (the DBA designers seem to agree with the 1000 column limit).

Comment: Or store the entire matrix as a blob. If you don't have to index the individual values, there's no need to store them as columns.

Answer (score 2):

Have a table of matrices, and another table which contains the doubles (also containing the id from the table of matrices). With 4096 rows on the second table for each row on the first table

```
CREATE TABLE Matrices
(
    Id INT,
    Matrix_Description VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE MatrixDoubles
(
    Id INT,
    Matrices_Id INT,
    SomeDoubleValue DOUBLE(16,2)
)
```